# Parse json string of the underline format to compare the values with another map

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string that looks like:

"{\"info\":{\"length\":{\"value\":18},\"name\":{\"value\":\"ABC\"}}}"

say, length and name are attribute names

I have another map (say attributeMap) that (created from the results I retrieve from the database) map has attribute name and attribute value association stored.
I need to be able to parse the string and compare the value an attribute has in the above string with the value returned from the attributeMap. Based on those comparisons, I will need to take some decisions.

In order to do this, I should convert the above string to a format that would help make the above comparison easier and efficient. I don't think I should be writing my own parser to do this. what would a right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use any JSON Parser, like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) (Google) (Recommended for simplicity), [JACKSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), the simple [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html), or any other..

Then you will get a JSONObject/JSONNode to navigate and do the comparison.

You can find a parsing example here: [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)